# Unable to resolve a plugin using the new plugin mechanism in Gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

While trying to upgrade some of our scripts to Gradle 4.0.1 on of the plugins we are using is failing and I thought of fixing that plugin first. The plugin is a third party open source project.

So I have cloned the project and tried to compile it. However it fails with following message:

```
c:\source\gradle-xld-plugin>gradlew build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\source\gradle-xld-plugin\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.plugin-publish', version: '0.9.7'] was not found in 
any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- maven(https://artifactory/java-v) (Could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.gradle.plugin-publish:com.gradle.plugin-publish.gradle.plugin:0.9.7')

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --
debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

The build.gradle script for the plugin starts like this:

```
plugins {
  id "com.gradle.plugin-publish" version "0.9.7"
  id "com.github.hierynomus.license" version "0.11.0"
  id 'nebula.nebula-release' version '4.0.1'
  id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.7.3"
}
```

In addition to this the company policy dictates we have to go through an internal artifactory server, so following has been added to the settings.gradle file:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory/java-v"
        }
    }
}
```

The jar file exists at following location: https://artifactory/java-v/com/gradle/publish/plugin-publish-plugin/0.9.7/plugin-publish-plugin-0.9.7.jar

but when I look at the error message I am a little puzzled that it says that it cannot find com.gradle.plugin-publish:com.gradle.plugin-publish.gradle.plugin:0.9.7. 
It seems to have suffixed the id with .gradle.plugin.

Does anyone know whether I am looking at the wrong location or how come it is suffixing the id with .gradle.plugin. And shouldn't it look at a location that has the GAV like this: com.gradle.plugin-publish:com.gradle.plugin-publish:0.9.7?

And does anyone know about how the resolution mechanism for the new plugin mechanism in Gradle works.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**
Thanks to Mateusz Chrzaszcz I was able to progress.

The only caveat I have with the solution is that it seems like a workaround rather than a solution. But it works!

In addition to his solution you had to resolve the plugins. I was able to hack my way to actually resolve the appropriate names.

In order to do so one has to do as follows:

1. In a webbrowser go for the plugin: id "com.github.hierynomus.license" version "0.11.0" go to following URL: https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle/4.0.1/plugin/use/com.github.hierynomus.license/0.11.0
2. The json returned contains the GAV needed in the useModule call. Use that

The following serves as an example:

```
resolutionStrategy {
    eachPlugin {
        if (requested.id.namespace == 'com.gradle' && requested.id.name == 'plugin-publish') {
            useModule('com.gradle.publish:plugin-publish-plugin:0.9.7')
        } else if(requested.id.namespace == 'com.github.hierynomus' && requested.id.name == 'license') {
            useModule('nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.11.0')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you were able to progress thanks to Mateusz Chrzaszcz, then at least you should upvote his answer.

Comment: Well @tbsalling I actually did, 3 times, however SO states the following: Thanks for the feedback ! Votes cast those with less than 15 reputation are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score. So unless you have some suggestion. I am can't do anything else than showing my appreciation in the edit message

Comment: Oh. Sorry. We have to get your reputation up, then :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try to implement Plugin Resolution Rules.

According to gradle documentation:

> Plugin resolution rules allow you to modify plugin requests made in plugins {} blocks, e.g. changing the requested version or explicitly specifying the implementation artifact coordinates.
>   To add resolution rules, use the resolutionStrategy {} inside the pluginManagement {} block

like that:

```
pluginManagement {
 resolutionStrategy {
  eachPlugin {
      if (requested.id.namespace == 'com.gradle.plugin-publish') {
          useModule('com.gradle.plugin-publish:0.9.7') //try a few combinations
      }
  }
}
repositories {
  maven {
    url 'https://artifactory/java-v'
  }
 }
}
```

Keep in mind this is incubating feature though.